# Can I simplify an expression by taking out a variable which is present within an integral and a non integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was integrating $sec^ 3(x)$ however during the process I found myself trying to divide a variable to simplify the expression (which would not have helped me as I realised after like 2 seconds) but nonetheless I’m curious whether this is legal.

If I have an integral such as

$$\int sec^3(x)  dx$$

And I want to evalute it so I take it by parts

$$\int sec^3(x) dx = tan(x)*sec(x) - \int tan^2(x) * sec(x) $$

Now in this case in order to evaluate the integral I would have to use a trig identity on the right side of the integral, but out of curiousity, even if it leads to nowhere and doesn’t help me, could I divide by sec(x) and get rid of the sec(x) on all the terms? Or would this be considered illegal?

I’m guessing it’s illegal because sec takes in x as an input and we are integrating with respect to x but I’m not sure whether I am 100% correct, also since sin(x) is not a constant. But I’m not too sure since I’ve had many things that blew my mind while learning this area of maths.

Anyways would this be considered legal?

Comment: Illegal. Always consider antiderivatives  in $x$ as $\int_0^x f(u) du$, no access to anything dependent on $u$

Comment: Awesome makes sense, thank you so much!